# std::priority_queue::pop iterators invalidating

Tags: c++, std, heap

Does using `priority_queue::pop()` function invalidate other heap elements iterators?
For example, I have minheap with elements `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and iterator `it` pointing to element with value `2`. Will be `*it` valid after applying pop to this heap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no (at least in the usual case--see more below).

`pop` on a priority queue is equivalent to:

```cpp
pop_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
c.pop_back();
```

...where `c` is a reference to the underlying container.

`pop_heap` itself only rearranges elements into the underlying collection--swaps the first and last elements in the container, then makes the first through last-1 elements back into a heap.

By default the underlying container will be `std::vector`, in which case the `pop_back` invalidates any iterators that refer to the element just removed, and potentially any past-the-end iterators.

The only other standard container you might reasonably use as the underlying container for a `priority_queue` would be a `std::deque`, which works pretty much the same way--`pop_back` will invalidate iterators to that element, and one-past-the-end iterators. (Note: I'm not saying there's a good reason to use a `deque` instead of a `vector`, just that you could do it, and it wouldn't necessarily be a huge problem).

If you wanted to badly enough, you could design some container of your own, and instantiate a `priority_queue` over that, in which case `pop` on the `priority_queue` would still do a `pop_back` on the underlying container, with whatever effects that happened to have. Although I can pretty easily see this being something like a `vector` plus a mutex (or similar) to allow sharing between threads, I think it would be fairly unusual to instantiate a `priority_queue` over a container with significantly different iterator invalidation rules than a `vector` or `deque`.

#### References

- [priqueue.members]/6

  > `void pop();`
  >
  > Effects: As if by:

  ```cpp
      pop_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
      c.pop_back();
  ```
- [deque.modifiers]/4

  > Effects: An erase operation that erases the last element of a deque invalidates only the past-the-end iterator and all iterators and references to the erased elements.
- [vector.modifiers]/3

  > Effects: Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase.